# cocos2d and UINavigationController trouble

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on an app where I'd like to use cocos2d in the app's home screen, but not elsewhere (in other places standard UIKit stuff is more appropriate). So, I've got my EAGLView set up as the root view in a UINavigationController, and when the user taps in the right place I push a new view controller onto the nav controller.

That's working great, so far. The cocos2d/chipmunk stuff in the home view is working great, pushing a new view controller works as expected.

But when I pop back to the home view, nothing's there. All I see is the window background and the navigation bar.

I set a breakpoint in the root view controller's -viewDidAppear: to see what's going on after the pop, and so far everything appears normal (or at least the same as it was before the push).

The push is just a bog-standard nav controller push. I'm not seeing any kind of memory warnings. Anyone have thoughts on what's going on?

There's a simple demo project that shows this behavior at http://cl.ly/1Q050s0h2k47032K1Y1N

This is based on the cocos2d+chipmunk project template. Tap on Grossini and a new view controller is pushed onto the stack. Tap the back button, and Grossini is gone.

And just to make it interesting, this problem only exists on an iOS device (I'm running 4.1), not in the simulator.

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but you're leaking these two guys: http://cl.ly/1J26180i383F3H0z3V2L

Comment: I'm not even sure what those are, but they don't look related.

Comment: I found that if my -viewDidLoad calls -setNeedsLayout on the EAGLview, the cocos2d objects are restored and the main view is visible after the navigation controller pops to root. There is a noticeable flicker, though-- for a moment, the cocos2d objects are not visible, but then they appear.

A modified version of my demo which incorporates this is at http://cl.ly/1L423a1x27373t1q0s0y

This feels like progress but it's a nasty flicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved your problem.
You have to follow some steps in your code.

In RootViewController nib file change the view Identity from HomeView to UIView.

Create a Home View Object in the RootViewController Class

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    HomeView *homeViewObj;
}
```

in RootViewController.m file in ViewDidLoad method add this code

```
homeViewObj = [[HomeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:homeViewObj];
```

and replace this code in your ViewDidLoad method at required place.

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setOpenGLView:(EAGLView *)homeViewObj];

    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];
```

Then the problem will be solved, All the best.

Regards,

Satya

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem. I don't completely understand why, though. Can you explain it at all?

Comment: Tom, I executed your code and tested it, I found one thing, when you come back to home View, it is not showing the "EAGLView" but it is detecting the touches and performing the operations. At the time of double tapping, the view went to 2ndView Controller and then I click back, then is showed the EAGLView. Then I understood that some view is overlay on the "EAGLView", so I put normal view in the InterfaceBuilder and added the EAGLView as sub view. Then the problem solved

Comment: Hey!! I was looking for the same, Thanx Satya